# Append list of lists elements in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I'm learning Prolog for about a week, so I'm a newbie.
I'm trying to do a function, that appends, the elements of a list of lists.

So the input would be: `[ [[a,b,c],[g,h,i]], [[j,k,l],[m,n,o]], [[s,t,u],[v,w,x]] ].`

And the output would be : `[ [a,b,c,j,k,l,s,t,u], [g,h,i,m,n,o,v,w,x] ].`

Or

Input: `[ [[a,b], [c,d]], [[e,f], [g,h]], [[i,j],[k,l]] ].`

Output: `[ [a,b,e,f,i,j], [c,d,g,h,k,l] ].`

It would be important, that it has to work with a lot of elements, not only 3.
I wrote this, but it only works with 2 elements, so i can only do it, with pairs.

```
merge([],[],[]).
merge(L1,[],L1).
merge([H1|T1],[H2|T2],LL):-
   append(H1, H2, HE),
   merge(T1,T2,TE),
   append([HE], TE, LL).
```

Comment: Questions: 1) Is the input a single list with lists of two lists? 2) Do you know that the lists of lists are all of the length 2?

Comment: No, it could be more than 2. 3,4 etc.

Comment: So at the end, if the first argument is a list of _n_ lists, each with _m_ sublists in it, the result will be a list with _m_ sublists?

Comment: BTW, is this a general Prolog question or is it somehow specific to SICSTUS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly...

First, if you know that your input has exactly two levels of nesting in it, and if your Prolog had higher-order predicates for mapping and for folding, and if you could compose them, you could simply write:

```
merge_foldl([], []).
merge_foldl([X|Xs], R) :-
    reverse([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]),
    foldl(maplist(append), Ys, Y, R).
```

This works as expected for SWI-Prolog.
Here it is with your two examples:

```
?- merge_foldl([ [[a,b,c],[g,h,i]], [[j,k,l],[m,n,o]], [[s,t,u],[v,w,x]] ], R).
R = [[a, b, c, j, k, l, s, t, u], [g, h, i, m, n, o, v, w, x]].

?- merge_foldl([ [[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]], [[g,h], [i,j], [k,l]] ], R).
R = [[a, b, g, h], [c, d, i, j], [e, f, k, l]].
```

If you don't have access to neither `foldr` nor `foldl`, you would have to hardcode the folding:

```
merge([], []).
merge([X|Xs], Result) :-
    merge_maplist(Xs, X, Result).

merge_maplist([], Result, Result).
```

This is not all, but it says that if you are at the end of the list of lists, the last element is the result.

Now you have to define the step where you append to the front of each sublist. This is easier with `maplist`:

```
merge_maplist([X|Xs], Prev, Result) :-
    merge_maplist(Xs, X, Result0),
    maplist(append, Prev, Result0, Result).
```

Note that here we are "emulating" a right fold by using a non-tail-recursive definition: we are doing the appending in reverse, after the recursive step. For a tail-recursive definition (identical to hard-coded left fold), you would have to reverse the original list first!

So you keep on peeling off one list of lists from your input until you are done. Then, you use `maplist` to apply `append/3` to each pair of lists from the previous element and the result so far, to get the final result.

If you don't have access to `maplist` either, you'd have to hardcode the mapping as well. For the three arguments that `append/3` takes:

```
map_append([], [], []).
map_append([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs]) :-
    append(X, Y, Z),
    map_append(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

and your `merge/2` and `merge_/3` become:

```
merge([], []).
merge([X|Xs], Result) :-
    merge_(Xs, X, Result).

merge_([], Result, Result).
merge_([X|Xs], Prev, Result) :-
    merge_(Xs, X, Result0),
    map_append(Prev, Result0, Result).
```

This is a lot of code for something that can be solved quite nicely if you have higher-order predicates.

Comment: How can i use the library, that uses maplist?

Comment: @gyeresicsaba I don't know SICSTUS in detail, which is why I showed how you can define it yourself. Search the documentation for `map` or `maplist` would be one way to do it.

Comment: @gyeresicsaba This is a really convoluted problem statement though, is it homework or do you need it for something practical?

Comment: Thank You so much, it works! I'm trying to do my own version btw. :)

Comment: It's a part of my homework. I have to divide a matrix, to specified size of matrices. I did it in Erlang a week ago, but Prolog is a bit different, and i stuck with this.

Comment: @gyeresicsaba One way you could do it differently would be to merge the three cases -- 1) empty list 2) list with one element and 3) list with two or more elements -- into three clauses of the same predicate. In some (most?) Prologs this will leave you with an unnecessary choice point. There is of course the issue of using Stackoverflow for homework, but this is between you and your instructors.

Comment: I made a function that appends the first elements of the sublists.
So in that case :
[ [[a,b], [c,d], [e,f]], [[g,h], [i,j], [k,l]] ], the output will be:
[a,b,g,h].
After that i throw these elements away, with another function.
I will have this list: [ [[c,d],[e,f]], [[i,j], [k,l]] ]. And than i recursively do this.

Comment: [`:- use_module(library(lists)).`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dlists.html#index-maplist_002f_005b2_002c3_002c4_005d-_0028lists_0029-1) for `maplist` in SICStus 4.